# Search using Place Autocomplete with Place Types in Android & iOS

Tags: android, ios, swift, autocomplete, google-places-api

I want to get a list of airports as per user search via [Google Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete). I have found the TYPE = "AIRPORT" from [Place Types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)

After reading the document I found that we can set different filters listed below.

```
 - kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterNoFilter
 - kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterGeocode
 - kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterAddress
 - kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterEstablishment
 - kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterCity
 - kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterRegion
```

> (A) locality (B) sublocality (C) postal_code (D) country (E)
>   administrative_area_level_1 (F) administrative_area_level_2

Now my question is We can apply above filter but how can we apply `Place Type`.

My purpose is to get the only list of Airports while search and get his address while choosing from the list.

Can I achieve this ? If yes how. Please guide me with some reference links.
I want to do this task in android & iOS both.

Thanks